# Mean Differences in Poisson Regression

Tags: group-differences, poisson-regression, contrasts, lsmeans

I performed a Poisson regression.  My dependent variable is number of days and my independent variables are all binary indicators (e.g. facility = facility1 facility2, facility3 and severity = extreme, major, moderate, minor and treatment level=high, medium, low).  So my model looks like this:

$\log(\mu)=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+\beta_4X_4+\beta_5X_5+\beta_6X_6+\beta_7X_7+\beta_8X_8+\beta_9X_9+\beta_{10}X_{10}$

where $X_1-X_3$ are the binary facility indicators, $X_4-X_7$ are the binary severity indicators and $X_8-X_{10}$ are the binary treatment indicators.

I am interested in obtaining the mean predicted differences for a given facility and severity between each of the treatment levels.  It is straight forward for me to obtain a point estimate.  For example, to compare high to low treatments in facility 1 and extreme severity, I simply calculate:

$\hat{Z}=\hat{\mu}_{1,4,8}-\hat{\mu}_{1,4,10}=\exp(\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1+\hat{\beta}_4+\hat{\beta}_8)-\exp(\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1+\hat{\beta}_4+\hat{\beta}_{10})$

Now, I need to calculate the variance of this estimate (in order to obtain confidence intervals).  I understand that I can get this using the Taylor Series/Delta Method approach by linearizing $Z.$  I have been able to obtain these variance estimates using SAS' `nlmixed` for a single difference (high-low) (see [here](http://support.sas.com/kb/37/344.html) for a SAS note that explains something very similar), but I was wondering if these is any way to conveniently obtain these variance estimates using without having to specify every single estimate statement.  I'm looking for a way to compare all pairwise treatments (similar to using an `lsmeans` statement in SAS).  I'm well versed in SAS, R, and dabble in STATA, and can use any of these if there are suggestions.  I just want to have to avoid specifying every single parameter to obtain all combinations of my estimates (which in my actual model contains over 60 parameters -- this was just a simplified example).

Comment: Given your predictors are all binary, one possibility to consider is actually fitting your model with an identity link; this would somewhat simplify the calculation of standard errors.

Comment: @Glen_b, I was thinking about doing just this.  Can you comment on what the pros and cons of using the identity link would be?  Why are log links so often used when an identity link could be used and simply matters?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to apply a couple statistical principles. You can estimate the mean difference pretty easily, just use the "predict" command. But getting an approximate confidence interval is difficult. You *could* bootstrap the data to get an efficient robust 95% exact interval (very attractive indeed), or you can use a normal approximation to the difference.

The LSMeans command does the former, however if you were fitting a mixed effects model (as would be done with nlmixed), there are many more considerations (too many to discuss). It's beyond the scope of the answer. Therefore, I'll assume you fit a plain old Poisson regression model using `myglm.fit <- glm(..., family=poisson)` as you've said.

The normal approximation is easily computed using the delta method. The covariance matrix for the parameter estimates $\Sigma$ is obtained by computing `Sigma <- vcov(myglm.fit)`.

Note $\hat{\mu}_1 = \exp \left( X_1 \hat{\beta} \right)$ and similarly for $\hat{\mu}_2$. Then $f(u, v) = \exp(u) - \exp(v)$ and $\nabla f(u, v) = [f(u, v), -f(u, v)]$. Using your notation $Z = f(X_1 \hat{\beta}, X_2 \hat{\beta})$. We can computer the variance of those components, it's just $X_1 \Sigma X_1^T$ and $X_2 \Sigma X_2^T$, and the covariance is $X_1 \Sigma X_2^T$. The $2\times 2$ covariance matrix is $\Xi = [X_1, X_2] \Sigma [X_1, X_2]^T$.

The Delta method, then, is simply applied:

$$\mbox{Var} (Z) = \nabla f \Xi \nabla f^T$$

and that is an approximate, asymptotically correct 95% confidence interval.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)

## from ?glm
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts)
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())

## create the proper levels x_1, x_2 to create linear combos
new.data <- data.frame(outcome = factor(c(1, 3), levels=1:3), 
                       treatment=factor(c(1,3), levels=1:3))


## how to create a lsmeans statement using delta method
lincom <- model.matrix(formula(glm.D93)[-2], data=new.data)
mu12 <- exp(lincom %*% beta)
nabla <- matrix(c(mu12[1], -mu12[2]), c(1,2))
Z <- diff(mu12)
varZ <- nabla %*% lincom %*% Sigma %*% t(lincom) %*% t(nabla)

## CI:
Z + c(-1.96 * sqrt(varZ), 1.96 * sqrt(varZ))

## ex bootstrap
bs <- replicate(1000, {
  d.AD[, 'counts'] <- rmultinom(n = 1, size=sum(counts), prob = counts/sum(counts))
  glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, data=d.AD, family = poisson())
  diff(predict(glm.D93, newdata=new.data, type='response'))
})

quantile(bs, c(0.25, 0.975))
```

Giving disparate results for CIs:

```
> Z + c(-1.96 * sqrt(varZ), 1.96 * sqrt(varZ))
[1] -15.281464   4.614797

> quantile(bs, c(0.25, 0.975))
    25%   97.5% 
-8.6350  3.8875
```

Comment: Thank you soo much!  I really appreciate the response with code.  I know how to do all the calculations by hand/manually, but was looking for a quick way to automate this.  You have shown me just the way.  I too was also contemplating a bootstrap approach and believe this might be the way to go.  As you said, I can get those easily, without having to calculate a bunch of partial derivates.  

Just as an FYI, since I didn't make it clear in my response, I am using a GEE approach using SAS' proc genmod.  I should be able to adapt your code to work with R's geepack or geeglm.

Comment: I'm going to leave the post open for a few days to see if anyone offers any SAS solutions.  If not, I'll accept your answer!  By the way, I realize the bootstrap isn't quite as straightforward in the GEE case, but I can modify your code to work with the bootstrap.

Comment: @Analyst1 yes GEE is a good choice, be sure to estimate the sigma using the `robust.variance` component. GEE in SAS is not estimated with nlmixed though, you use the genmod procedure. Can you compute LSMeans with that?

Comment: Yes.  I'm already doing that.  Model based estimates are garbage.  Thanks for much for your help!

Comment: if you take a look at this SAS note (http://support.sas.com/kb/37/344.html), you cannot calculate the *difference* in means as I was hoping in an lsmeans statement.  I was using lsmeans with genmod to obtain the individual mean estimates.  I was thinking about using nlmixed to obtain CI's of these differences.

Comment: @Analyst1 You seem to know your stuff pretty well. It turns out that it's more efficient to calculate an additive rate model using a poisson variance with an identity link. Then you can get your estimates directly from the parametrization.

Comment: Thanks, @AdamO.  You too!  In case you are interested, here's a SAS note on fitting "genmod" models in nlmixed:  http://support.sas.com/kb/56/549.html