Confidence interval for the difference of 2 poisson means
I have 2 samples drawn from 2 poisson distributions. My null hypothesis was that the 2nd distribution had a mean that is equal or greater than the 1st distribution. I tested this hypothesis at the 95% confidence level with a poisson mean test (a.k.a. E-test). The p-value turned out to be lesser than 0.05, so I rejected the null hypothesis.
Now that I am confident that the 2nd poisson distribution has a lower mean than the 1st, how can I express how much lower the 2nd distribution's mean is as a confidence interval?
For instance, I can say that the mean of the sample from the 2nd distribution is 30% less than the mean of the sample from the 1st distribution. But how can I say that the 2nd distribution's mean is (25%,35%) less than the 1st distribution with 95% confidence? (Values just for illustrative purposes)

If you want a two-sided confidence interval, should you have used a two-tailed test?  With R, using poisson.test(c(100, 70)) would give you a confidence interval for $\lambda_x/\lambda_y$ of $[1.04,1.97]$ and so for $\lambda_y/\lambda_x$ of $[0.51,0.96]$

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202866/mean-differences-in-poisson-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279731/a-mover-confidence-interval-for-the-ratio-of-two-poisson-rates, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/checking-if-two-poisson-samples-have-the-same-mean, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109402/c-test-for-comparing-poisson-means-in-scipy
